# Exception in thread "main" dropbox application

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, dropbox

I'm trying to make a simple application with Java, using Eclipse that could upload a file from my computer to Dropbox but whenever I compile, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/params/ConnPerRoute
    at javaaplication1.JavaApplication11.main(JavaApplication11.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnPerRoute
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Can you help me figure this out? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You miss the `httpclient.jar` in your classpath. Download it and add it to your classpath.

Comment: Same exception? Wich version of httpClient.jar do you use?

Comment: Now I'm getting this: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet
 at com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility.streamRequest(RESTUtility.java:164)
 at com.dropbox.client2.session.WebAuthSession.setUpToken(WebAuthSession.java:218)
 at com.dropbox.client2.session.WebAuthSession.getAuthInfo(WebAuthSession.java:158)
 at com.dropbox.client2.session.WebAuthSession.getAuthInfo(WebAuthSession.java:128)
 at DropboxAuthTest.main(DropboxAuthTest.java:47)
` And I tried using different versions of that library and it was the same, now I'm using 4.3.5 .

Comment: Then you need the [apapche common  httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) too.